# python scraping for javascript not working and specific data

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

to begin, i wanted to **scrape** this table that load from java script and i only want to **scrape** specific row of data such as base on Fund abbreviation or search base on that, but my basic script here is not working well. please help

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.publicmutual.com.my/Our-Products/UT-Fund-Prices'
r = session.get(url)
r.html.render()
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'fundtable col-sm-12'})
print(table)
```

how do i make this work and **scrape** information only certain rows that i wanted based on the fund name or fund abbreviation column?

Comment: is it a soup or a rendering problem ?

Comment: not really sure about that tho, how can i check in this case?

Comment: using the browser copy paste the source code and save it as file, then parse it

Comment: i am able to scrap with the file from source code with the given class name for the table.

Comment: Use ```selenium```

Answer (score 0):

If you go in chromedevtools and check for the url that render the table you will see the html of the table as follow:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjxEu.png)

The website perform a post request to get the
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIDhS.png)

If you need that your **scraping** application been fast you have to map the payload and scrapy with python-requests and bs4. If speed is not a problem you can use python-Selenium

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).